# How to use generators in nested loops in python

Tags: python, django, memory-management, generator, nested-loops

I have a piece of code like this:

```
def populate_table():
    countries = CM.objects.all() # around 250 records
    for country in countries:
        destinations = Dest.objects.filter(country__iexact=country.name) # maximum 100 records
        for destination in destinations:
            i_c = IC.objects.all() # 13 million records
            for i_ca in i_c:
                o_c = OC.objects.all() # 15 million records
                for o_ca in o_c:
                    objs = []
                    tt = Time.objects.all() # 80000 records
                    for t in tt:
                        attrs = {'country': country, 'destination': destination, 'time': t, 'i_c': i_ca, 'o_c': o_ca}
                        total_amount = random.uniform(0.5000, 1.4000)
                        attrs['total_amount'] = round(total_amount, 4)
                        objs.append(FactRates(**attrs))
                    obj = FactRates.objects.bulk_create(objs)
```

I tried to use generators, but failed. Can some one help me out how can I use generators efficiently so that I may consume less memory and make it rapid.
This piece of code eats my 8GB memory and my laptop hangs. Please help me out.

Comment: Why don't you put `objs` outside all loops and make the `bulk_create` operation only once, after all objects have been created?

Comment: Also, why don't you invert loops and move iteration for country and destination inside IC and OC objects iteration? Whatever optimization you apply to the most expensive iterations (IC and OC) will be defeated by being done several times for being inside less expensive loops.